# Android application compatibility

Tags: android, application, google

Sailfish OS can run Android applications through a proprietary compatibility layer. Are there any other mobile operating systems capable of this?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Google play apps are just Android apps.

Comment: Sailfish OS can run Android applications through a proprietary compatibility layer. Are there any other mobile operating systems capable of this?

Comment: Thats a much better question just make that your question.